# JFrame layout with radio buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jradiobutton

This is my code:

```
frame2 = new JFrame("Confirmation");
        frame2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JRadioButton y,n,c;
         panel = new JPanel();
          ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
          y = new JRadioButton("Add");
          buttonGroup.add(y);
          panel.add(y);
          n = new JRadioButton("Update");
          buttonGroup.add(n);
          panel.add(n);
          c = new JRadioButton("Delete");
          buttonGroup.add(c);
          panel.add(c);
          y.setSelected(true);
          b1=new JButton();
          b1.setBounds(300,100,2,2);
          b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(searchresult.class.getResource("/images/yes.png")));
          b2=new JButton();
          b2.setBounds(100,10,2,2);
          b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(searchresult.class.getResource("/images/no.png")));
          panel.add(b1);
          panel.add(b2);
          frame2.add(panel);
          frame2.setSize(182,150);
          frame2.setVisible(true);
```

Right now this gives me the following output
[image]

whereas I want this 
[image]

with an increased width but I am not able to do it..Could anyone provide me with further details that could help me

Comment: No offense, but that code is kind of an eyesore.  You should modularize/reorganize it.

Comment: this is not the actual code.Just for an example

Comment: Nonetheless, the easier your code is to read/comprehend, the more likely someone will be to answer your question.  Plus, it's just good practice.

Comment: I will keep that in mind.But could you provide me any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, which, as the name suggests, layouts out components one after the after, in a flow...

Two choices.  Use a compound layout, using `BorderLayout` as the base, create `JPanel` that uses a `GridLayout` for the radio buttons (using `0` rows and `1` column), add this to the `CENTER` position of the base panel.

Create a second `JPanel` using a `FlowLayout` and your buttons to it.  Add this to the `SOUTH`  position of the base pane.

Second choice is to use a `GridBagLayout`

Take a look at [Laying out Components within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details